# jQuery checkbox and span that share a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a checkbox and a span

`<input type="checkbox" class="checker"> <span class="something">Label</span>`

From which the span already has some functionality based on clicking it, I am adding a checkbox to the equation for visual aid. What I am trying to do is, when the checkbox is checked/unchecked I want it to trigger the spans already existing click function. Which this I can do.

I also want the same click function on the span to check/uncheck the checkbox next to it, while continuing its base function. Which this I can do as well.

The snag it seems is when I have both logics in the script, one will always X out the other, leaving one working and the other not. So I am trying to figure out how to make this work in harmony and I apparently am having issues thinking outside the box at the time and need some assistance getting there.

Here is the JS I am attempting to use currently

```
$('.checker').live('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();$(this).siblings('.something').trigger('click');});
$('.something').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).siblings('.checker').is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).siblings('.checker').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings('.checker').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just add a `change` event handler to the checkbox and use a `label` instead of a `span`. The label and input are tied together. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `Label` Tag

```
<li class="contact">
    <input id='input1' type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkableitems[]" value="1333">
    <label for='input1'>Baby James</label>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/5/

Still you want it in your style then please refer this fiddle.

```
$('.something').on('click', function() {
    var chk_box = $(this).prev();
    var chk_status = !(chk_box.is(':checked'));
    chk_box.attr('checked', chk_status);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgB5X/10/

Comment: answer would suffice if I was looking to invoke the use of a label for what a label is intent for. However, in the event the checkbox was checked/unchecked by clicking on the checkbox itself and not the label I still needed to trigger the the click event on the span. While recognizing if the checkbox was checked/unchecked on click of the actual checkbox or span.. no worries though I have since figured out my solution. But just wanted to put in my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by using a `label` element will ensure that your elements are linked together as desired as this solution will not require any interaction with JavaScript or jQuery, if the elements don't require any other special actions.

Avoid the usage of `live()` and opt-in for either `on()` (>= v1.7) or `delegate()` ( < v1.7).

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="check1"> <label for="check1">Label 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="check2"> <label for="check2">Label 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="check3"> <label for="check3">Label 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" id="check4"> <label for="check4">Label 4</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.checker').each(function(){
    $(this).on('change', function(){
        $('.checker').not('#' + this.id).attr('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EWK4M/